# IPhone .sqlite file place

Tags: iphone

How can I change the place of the .sqlite file in my directory structure. Now it is in the Documents, but I want it to be in the Library/Preferences. Can you help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have something like this in your code:

`[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];`

Try replacing `NSDocumentDirectory` with `NSLibraryDirectory`.

I am not sure where and if you are allowed to write files there (except by using the sanctioned methods, of course).